# Reactjs setstate from a json

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

 const getItems= () => {
  fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/invoice/Draft/1`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-business-name' : 'billings',
    "Accept":"application/json"
  },

})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(items => setItems(items))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

 useEffect(() => {
getItems()
}, []);
```

i wanna get the data from a json and put them in this state

```
  const [lineItems, setLineItems] = useState([
{

  name: '',
  description: '',
  quantity: 1,
  price: 0.00,
},
 ]);
```

when i tried

```
    console.log(items.length > 0 && items[0].items && items[0].items.map(item => item.name)[0])
```

it showed me the item i wanna get
[this is the result of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHs35.png)

now i wanna insert that number into my state in place of

```
  quantity: 1,
```

and finally this is how my json looks like

```
 [
   {
"id": 1,
"invoiceno": "4",
"description": "facture",
"taxrate": 10,
"issuedate": "2021-07-14T23:00:00.000Z",
"duedate": "2021-07-08T23:00:00.000Z",
"note": "facture",
"taxamount": 10,
"subtotal": 100,
"total": 100,
"updatedAt": null,
"updatedBy": null,
"createdAt": "2021-07-31T16:40:43.000Z",
"createdBy": 0,
"items": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "milk",
        "item": 12,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 500,
        "idInvoice": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "water",
        "item": 12,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 500,
        "idInvoice": 1
    }
      ]
     }
       ]
```

i want to have the items ( item quantity price description all in my state from the json)

Comment: I assume that you succeeded in fetching that json data, and now u need to format it into another array containing only `description`, `quantity`, and `price`. I dont recommend using another state for that. Anyway, this is how I looped throug your sample data to create the short array: https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/dyzMgVM?editors=0010

Comment: that didnt help with my issue cause i have to initilize them in a state

Comment: const [lineItems, setLineItems] = useState([
    {
      name: newItems.name,
      description: '',
      quantity: 1,
      price: 0.00,
    },
  ]);
i want something like this i tried calling it newItems.name still doesnt work

Comment: With state: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-starter-forked-rouq8?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Sorry if I don't get your issue

Comment: this is still not working in my case from some reason when i do console.log(lineitems) the state you made for me it just shows returns false